# Matrix equality with identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

> Given two matrices $A$ and $B$. To show:
>
> Part 1: $(I+AB)^{-1}=I-A(I+BA)^{-1}B$, provided $BA$ and $AB$ exist.
>
> Part 2: Let $a$ and $b$ be scalars. Using part 1, to show $(aI_{k}+bJ_{k})^{-1}=I_{k}/a -bJ_{k}/\{a(a+kb)\}$, where $I_p$ is the $p\times p$ identity matrix, and $J_p$ is the $p\times p$-matrix whose all entries are $1$.

My approach:

1st part:
$(I-A(I+BA)^{-1}B)(I+AB)=(I+AB)-A(I+BA)^{-1}B(I+AB)$
Since, $B(I+AB)=B+BAB=(I+BA)B$

$(I-A(I+BA)^{-1}B)(I+AB)=(I+AB)-A(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA)B=I$

Similarly, $(I+AB)(I-A(I+BA)^{-1}B)=I$

2nd part:
We have $aI_{k}+bJ_{k}=a(I_k+\frac{b}{a}1_k1_k^{\prime})$, where $1_k$ is the $k\times 1$ vector filled with ones.

Fix, $\frac{b}{a}1_k=A, 1_k^{\prime}=B$

We get,
$(aI_{k}+bJ_{k})^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}(I_k+\frac{b}{a}1_k1_k^{\prime})^{-1}$
$=\frac{1}{a}(I_k-\frac{b}{a}1_{k}(1+\frac{kb}{a})^{-1}1_k^{\prime})$
$=\frac{1}{a}(I_k-\frac{ab}{a(a+kb)}J_k)$
$=\frac{1}{a}(I_k-\frac{b}{a(a+kb)}J_k)$

I was wondering if you could review my work or suggest any alternative way to prove these problems. I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Could you please give me any hints to fix this?

Comment: @Barsal There is nothing to fix. All you write is correct.

Comment: Not so fast @amsmath; I just fixed a couple typos :) Also, $1_p$ and $1'_p$ should be defined.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I did so now (edit).

Answer (score 1):

You write $B(I+AB)=B+BAB=(I+AB)B$, but the last term should be $(I+BA)B$ (the order of $A$ and $B$ matters since $AB \neq BA$ in general).

I can't comment on the second part because I'm not sure what is meant by $J_p$ and $1_p$.

Comment: I am not confident about the second part. Edited 1st part!

Comment: I’m not seeing at all what the objection regarding $1_p$ is: the outer product of the column p-vector of ones with itself is certainly the p-by-p matrix of ones.

Comment: @Semiclassical You and OP are right.

Comment: My apologies, you are right.